# Remove duplicates from columns in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, duplicates, match, array-formulas

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KGpWneb5yHWbsr7V20n9oB1aibF6BCB2ii7sMURPLPc/edit?usp=sharing

In this link I am trying to demonstrate what I want google sheets to do; remove duplicates from column cells - row by row.

I've tried removing duplicates from cells, and by row, but haven't had any luck with removing them by column.

This is a pretty big database (2k+ entries), so really hoping to find a clean solution by putting this question out to the community.

Answer (score 3):

paste in **G2**:

```
={A3:A, ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(B3:E, A3:A, ))}
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

`=ARRAYFORMULA(A3:A)` in `G3` (or `=UNIQUE(A3:A)` if what is in the red frame is not ok).

And this in `H3`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(MATCH(B3:E, A3:A, 0), 0) <> 0, "", B3:E))
```

[image]